# Reconstructing associative arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to recunstruct this array with a foreach loop :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 0
            [NAME] => 400
            [QUANTITY] => 12
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 0
            [NAME] => 403
            [QUANTITY] => 108
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 5
            [NAME] => 403
            [QUANTITY] => 108
        )
)
```

This is what i want it to look like:

```
Array
(
    [ID] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => QUANTITY
            [NAME] => QUANTITY
        )
Array
(
    [ID] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => QUANTITY
        )
```

The code i came up with does not work properly, the array seems to be overwritten on every loop displaying only the last entry:

```
Array
(
    [ID] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => QUANTITY
        )
    [ID] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => QUANTITY
        )
)
```

This is my code:

```
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($result as $key=>$value){
        $i = $value["ID"];
        $x = $value["NAME"];
        $y = $value["QUANTITY"]; 
        $arr[$i] = array( $x=>$y);                    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($result as $key=>$value){
    $i = $value["ID"];
    $x = $value["NAME"];
    $y = $value["QUANTITY"]; 
    if(!isset($arr[$i])) $arr[$i] = array();
    $arr[$i][$x] = $y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't have the same key multiple times. it's imposible. an array must have a unique key.
you can create an array for the name key and it will look like this:

```
[ID] => Array
    (
        [NAME] => Array 
               (
                    [0] => QUANTITY
                    [1] => QUANTITY
               )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

As Vlad says you can't use the same index name...

But probably you want something like this:

```
foreach($result as $key=>$value){
    $i = $value["ID"];
    $x = $value["NAME"];
    $y = $value["QUANTITY"];

    // here you go:
    $data = array($x => $y);
    if (isset($arr[$i]) {
        $arr[$i] = array_merge($arr[$i], $data);
    } else {
        $arr[$i] = $data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php

$newArray = array();

foreach ($result as $value)
{
    $newArray[$value['id']] = array($value['NAME']=>$value['QUANTITY']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would help. Considering you declare your array.

```
$array = array(0 => array("id" => 0, "Name" => 400, "quantity" =>12),
                1 => array("id" => 0, "Name" => 403, "quantity" =>108),
                2 => array("id" => 5, "Name" => 403, "quantity" =>108)
);
```

And you declare a new array with no value nor construction.

```
$newArray = array();
```

Now, try this code!

```
foreach($array as $arr => $value)
{
    $id = $value["id"];
    $name = $value["Name"];
    $quantity = $value["quantity"];
    if(count($newArray[$id])>0){
        $newArray[$id] = array_merge($newArray[$id],array($name => $quantity));
    } else {
        $newArray[$id] = array($name => $quantity);
    }
}
```